# Mocking external methods returning struct in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, go, struct, mocking

I'm writing some code in Go. I want to unit test my code - a wrapper created for MongoDB Go Driver:

[mongodb-go-driver on GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver)

The problem is I don't know how to mock some functions of MongoDB internals (like collection's methods).

For example there is one function from collection.go:

```golang
func (coll *Collection) Find(ctx context.Context, filter interface{}, opts ...*options.FindOptions) (*Cursor, error) {
//...
}
```

I've created interface for Collection and mocks, to cover this functionality (something like that):

```golang
type IDBProviderCollection interface {
//...
Find(ctx context.Context, filter interface{}, opts ...*options.FindOptions) (*Cursor, error) 
}
```

The problem is that this function returns struct, which is too complex for doing some workarounds.
All i want is just to mock this function - to return cursor to fake data, and after cursor.Next() function in Cursor struct, there will be new fake data. Now it panics beacuse internals of mongo.Cursor are not satisfied, which is logical, beacuse I'm faking MongoDB database.

Comment: [Don't mock what you don't own](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don't-mock-what-you-don't-own)

Comment: To have control over the returned cursor behaviour you can write a couple of thin wrappers and glue them together, something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/gtPZCNvn2Ab

Comment: @mkopriva - i think you couldn't do that. Check my code. https://play.golang.org/p/6dUKZumAzTW

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/GwSLmXc-o0z

Comment: @mkopriva - the problem is that i need to mock method which has concrete struct in signature, and I can't change it (beacuse it's 3'rd part dependency).

Comment: That's why you need to wrap that 3rd party, the *mongo.Cursor, in a thin wrapper (the `MongoCursor` in the example) that implements an interface that's identical to the methods that *mongo.Cursor implements (the `MyCursor` in the example) and then modify your `IDBProviderCollection` to return that interface instead of the 3rd party. Here's an updated example https://play.golang.com/p/qSCakeEU_L1 with the 3rd party types mimicked by local types, and you can see the code compiles. It is an approach that works, I've tried it before.

Comment: ... note that in my original examples I was returning pointers to the interface i.e. `*MyCursor`, which is *wrong*, it should be just interface value as the return type, i.e. `MyCursor`. I've updated the last example so that one should be ok now.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I now understand what is going on in your code. Thanks.

Comment: Still, I think that @AlexBlex is right. Such code should be tested by integration tests, not unit tests. I think it's better to do that - creating bloated codebase is not good idea.

Comment: @AlexBlex, could you write this as an answer? I will accept it then.